# Constraint optimization in R using constrOptim

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I am trying to solve a system of equations with 2 matrices and a number of linear constraints:
matrix 1: 3x3 matrix m1
matrix 2: 1x3 matrix m2
my function is the following:
`const.fun<- function(m1,m2){t(m2)%*%m1%*%m2}`
As I have some constraints, I am using constrOptim (which I am not very familiar with so far) to solve with the following ui and ci:
`ui <- rbind(c(1,1,1),c(-1,-1,-1),c(1,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(0,0,1))`
`ci <- c(1,-1,0,0,0)`
The goal is to limit the sum of values in m2 to 1 and values to be non-negative, as if I correctly understand the direction of the constraints are always defined as ui * theta >= ci.
I use the following function to opimtize my values
`constrOptim(m2, const.fun,NULL, m1 = m1, ui = ui, ci = ci)`
However, R tells me: initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region.
I would greatly appreciate solution ideas with constrOptim or other packages.

Comment: Receiving solution ideas would be more likely if a complete reproducible problem were provided.

Comment: If matrix `m1` is positive definite this is quadratic programming problem and you can use `quadprog::solve.QP`. Because of equality constraint your feasible region does not have interior so I don't think you can use `constrOptim`.

Comment: Quadprog worked for this problem, thank you!